# Wrong values while accessing NativeElement

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to access height of a div in Angular2

HTML

```
<div #ccww c-w>

</div>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('ccww') CW;

ngAfterViewInit() {
 var cwElement = this.CW;
 console.log(cwElement);
 console.log(cwElement.nativeElement.clientHeight);
}
```

But when I log those values I get different `clientHeight`

This is the Logged value of `cwElement`
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3SL5.png)

As you can see above, the object contains a `clientHeight` with the value of 513

and the logged value of `cw.nativeElement.clientHeight` is 563

How do I properly access the correct value ? And why do I see an error ?

Comment: Try to use ngAfterViewChecked instead. Perhaps, something is rendered after the ngAfterViewInit event.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten Yes. You're right it's being changed in a fraction of seconds... but now`ngAfterViewChecked` is throwing me an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Comment: Are you changing a component property in it? Try to do this via setTimeout

Comment: Just an fyi, `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is only view-able in dev environment and doesn't hurt anything. It's simply confirming what your question is about... `#ccww` changes between viewInit and viewChecked.

Comment: I just used `detectChanges()` from the `ChangeDetectorRef ` Object. I get no error in dev environment too. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @darkermuffin Would you please with a sample plunk if my approach with setTimeout did not resolve the issue?

Comment: I also have the same issue, especially on firefox

Comment: I am also facing the same issue,has anyone found the reason

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like this

```
@ViewChild('ccww') CW: ElementRef;
```